# Are two real, two variable polynomials, satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations, a complex polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, analytic-functions

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ satisfying $u_{x} = v_{y}$ and $u_{y} = -v_{x}$ everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$. Is the function $f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ a polynomial in the variable $z = x +  iy$?

I really don't know where to start with this. I tried to build a counterexample, but I had no success.

Comment: Well since your function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations and your real and imaginary parts are continuously différentiable, your function is holomorphic. That means it has a power series expansion. Can you write it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that (as in the title) $u$ and $v$ are polynomial functions, then yes, it is true. The function $f$ is holomorphic and therefore analytic. And, since $u$ and $v$ are polynomial functions $f^{(n)}=0$ is $n$ is large enough. Therefore, $f$ is polynomial too.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can solve it now.

Comment: @RudáFloresta I'm glad I could help.